# Javascript/HTML Button Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I am trying to create a replication of windows calculator just for the sake of practicing jquery and Javascript (a basic one of course). I have created all the html buttons already. Now I am trying to display the numbers when clicked. Apparently, only "1" is shown when it is clicked. The other numbers aren't showing.

`$("button").attr("class")` only works for the first button

I did make all the buttons work utilizing

```
$(this).on("click", ".0", function() {
        var store=$(".draft").val().concat($(".0").val());
        $(".draft").val(store);
      });
```

but that would mean I need to repeat this code for all the digits which isn't efficient...

How would I efficiently get it to work for the other digits?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).on("click", "."+$("button").attr("class"), function() {
            var store=$(".draft").val().concat($("."+$("button").attr("class")).val());
            $(".draft").val(store);
        });
</script>

<input class="draft" type="text" style="height: 25px; width: 250px"/> <br> <br>
<button class="1" value="1" enabled style="position: center; height: 50px; width: 50px">1</button>
<button class="2" value="2" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">2</button>
<button class="3" value="3" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">3</button> 
<button class="divide" value="/" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">÷</button> <br>
<button class="4" value="4" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">4</button>
<button class="5" value="5" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">5</button>
<button class="6" value="6" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">6</button> 
<button class="multiply" value="*" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">*</button> <br>
<button class="7" value="7" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">7</button>
<button class="8" value="8" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">8</button>
<button class="9" value="9" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">9</button> 
<button class="subtract" value="-" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">-</button> <br>
<button class="0" value="0" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">0</button>    
<button class="plusminus" value="-" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">+/-</button>
<button class="dot" value="." enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">.</button> 
<button class="add" value="+" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">+</button> 
<button class="equal" value="=" enabled style="height: 50px; width: 50px">=</button>
```

Comment: give a common class to all your buttons or wrap them in a div whit a specified id, then bind an event to its button elements. for each item pressed retrieve its value, then use it to append the clicked btn value to your draft

Comment: Do not use classes for meta-data. Use `data-` attributes instead (or just use the `val()` of the clicked item) and leave classes for styling/selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using a single delegated event handler, connected to a parent element. This is more efficient than connecting loads of handlers:

```
$(function () {
    $('.calculator').on("click", "button", function () {
        // Do something with the value of the clicked button...
        $(".draft").val($(".draft").val() + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cf8csjw1/

It works by listening for events to bubble up to the ancestor element, then applying the jQuery selector, then calling your function for the element that caused the event in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I spent a couple hours trying to generalize the solution from my repeated codes without any luck...

onward to the harder stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to access the specific button you want to target.

```
$("button")
```

will return the first button in your DOM.
Instead, target by class or ID:

```
$(".1") //targets the element with a class of '1'
```

For your problem, you can get the value of the button by using 'this':

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var value = $(this).val()
  // do something with value

});
```

Comment: But that would require him to repeat the code for every class, which is a horrible solutuion

Comment: your last example won't work as this refers to the outer scope while the event is bounded

Answer (score 0):

I would think put it in an each, eg

```
 $.each($("button"),function(){
     $(this).attr("class");
 })
```

or

```
 $("button").each(function(){
     $(this).attr("class");
 })
```

Comment: Your code does nothing useful as shown. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is using the same class name for each button and after that using the $(this) option to read the value.

Here I have created a simple example with your code. It´s only your code with a few changes.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/huxosa/1/)

Comment: While your sample works, using the class is no different to using 'button' as the selector (as @Liam Schauerman suggested). It would be more efficient to use a single delegated event handler connected to a parent element of all those controls.

Comment: No problems, but it´s true, the best approach for a "real" app it´s using the @TrueBlueAussie solution.